# Why is Siphash-128 considered "experimental"?

Tags: siphash

Why is Siphash-128 still considered "experimental"?  What does this mean?

Comment: Probably that it's less-well-studied than the 64-bit version, so they can't promise that it's secure yet. But I can't find any discussion of that.

Comment: Has it even been published?

Comment: @otus it is on the GitHub of the reference implementation

Comment: @Demetri I meant publish in the academic sense.

Comment: In the meantime, [SipHash with 128-bit output was quietly changed to *not* be experimental on 2016-12-16](https://github.com/veorq/SipHash/commit/8388cbe24faceb3ed5b2f55a7c168ab48449f0c8#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8). As far as I know, SipHash with 128-bit output has neither been formally published nor analyzed much by the community.